# Angular 6 creating Radio button and Checkbox dynamically in Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to build controls first time using Reactive forms following this example:
https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Eventually, I will use service, but for now, I could create checkboxes by following the code. However, while trying to create radio buttons, but I keep getting -ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code in component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-report',
    templateUrl: './report.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss']
})
export class ReportComponent {
    form: FormGroup;
    orders = [
        { id: 100, name: 'chk 1' },
        { id: 200, name: 'chk 2' },
        { id: 300, name: 'chk 3' },
        { id: 400, name: 'chk 4' }
    ];

    streams = [
        { id: 1, name: 'radio 1' },
        { id: 2,  name: 'radio 2' }
    ];
    tmp: boolean = false;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        // Create a new array with a form control for each order
        const controls = this.orders.map(c => new FormControl(false));
        controls[0].setValue(true); // Set the first checkbox to true (checked)
  // updated code
     //for radio button
    const controlsR = this.streams.map(c => new FormControl(false));
    controls[0].setValue(true); // Set the first option to selected

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        orders: new FormArray(controls),
        streams: new FormArray(controlsR)
    });


    //this.form.addControl.name(controlsR);
    //this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    //    streams: new FormArray(controls)
    //});
    }
    submit() {
        const selectedOrderIds = this.form.value.orders
            .map((v, i) => v ? this.orders[i].id : null)
            .filter(v => v !== null);

        console.log(selectedOrderIds);
    }
}
```

and template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="cb-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'cb-vertical':!tmp}">
        <label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.orders.controls; let i = index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
            {{orders[i].name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <!--radio button-->
    <!--updated code-->
        <label formArrayName="streams" *ngFor="let stream of form.controls.streams.controls; let i = index">
        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="i">
        {{streams[i].name}}
    </label>

  <!--  <label formArrayName="streams" *ngFor="let stream of form.controls.streams.controlsR; let i = index">
        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="i">
        {{streams[i].name}}
    </label>-->

    <div *ngIf="!form.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are overwriting your `orders` formarray with `this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            streams: new FormArray(controlsR)
        });` You should add both in the same or use `addControl`. But fixing this, you will find an issue with your radio buttons ;)

Comment: AJT_82, I update code per your suggestion. Please verify. Now I can see radio buttons, but I am still not sure why in the template I have form.controls.streams.controls and form.controls.streams.controlsR does not work. Can you please explain? Thx